# Updated MX Record Causing Bounce

Tags: domain-name-system, email, mx-record, email-bounces

We recently migrated our company to a new mail provider (Gmail), and updated our MX/SPF/DKIM/DMARC records.

Checking the DNS propagation via https://dnschecker.org/, all changes are reflected.

However, when trying to send email to a specific person, we are receiving the following NDR:

```
This is an SMTP server at asp.reflexion.net

Your message could not be delivered to the following address: <**redacted**>

from <**redacted**> to <**redacted**>
**redacted**.mail.protection.outlook.com:***.***.***.*** failed after I sent the message. STARTTLS proto=TLSv1.2; cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384.
Remote host said: 550 5.4.1 All recipient addresses rejected : Access denied [**redacted**.protection.outlook.com]
```

Any advice on how to resolve? Is this just a cache issue on Outlook's part that will be resolved over time, or is there some configuration issues that we need to resolve on our end?

Comment: This is a (possible) problem with the domain of the user to whom you are sending the mail.

Comment: You probably need to `**redacted**` the `**redacted**`.